# Fourier transform of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I got a matrix in 'z', and I want to do the Fourier transform of that matrix, but in the answer it gives me a matrix same like 'z'. Why am I getting the Fourier transform of my data wrong?

```
%formula I(Q, t) = A exp[(-t/tau_beta)^beta]
% beta
clear;
beta = [0.4 0.6 0.8 1];

tau_beta = [1 10 100 1000];

t = [0:1:1e4];

% Division of (t/tbeta)

for m = 1:1:4
    y(m, :) = t/tau_beta(m);
end
A = 1;

for k = 1:4
    for j = 1:1:10001
        for i = 1:1:4
            %z(i, :) = y(j, :).^beta(i)

            z(i+(k-1)*(4), j) = A*exp(-y(i, j).^beta(k));

            zet(i+(k-1)*(4), j) = y(i, j).^beta(k);

            %I_temp(i, :) = z(i, :);

            %I(i, j, :) = I_temp(i, :);
            % Fourier Transform

            FT(i+(k-1)*(4), j) = abs(fft(z(i+(k-1)*(4), j)));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: why don't you use `fft2` ???

Comment: The Fourier transform (`fft` line) is _outside_ the loops, and it only fills one number, at position (16, 100001). All preceding values are intiatiallized to 0 by Matlab. You probably want to put that line within the loops. But still, at avery iteration you will be computing the FFT of a single number, which doesn't make sense

Comment: I put the fft under the loop but it doesn't do the fft of matrix . The result of 'z' and FT gave me same numbers which is wrong.